# Javascript page redirection results Method not allowed 405 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have get the result from ajax success method, on that method I have redirecting to another page but it always block me not allowing shows below error.

```
 page 405 method not allowed
```

How to fix this any suggestions welcomed I need to redirect to desired page.

This is I have tried:

```
function callinsert(db, tbl, pk, jobj) {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + at);
        },
        url: "MYURL/Insert?database=" + db + "&tablename=" + tbl + "&pk=" + pk,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: jobj,
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: OnSuccessInsertEmployee,
        /*Create a Function to run the Success Action */
        error: errorAction
    });

}



  function OnSuccessInsertEmployee(data) {
//Here I need to redirect to another page
        location.href = "xxxx.html";
    }
```

Comment: Try to window.location.replace(xxxx.html) OR window.location.href = "xxxx.html"

Comment: That's also not working bro I already tried it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using two different id names for the forms. On submit it will not getting the method to redirect.

Use the event.preventDefault() jquery function on submit of Form in your script.

Comment: Thanks bro..You save my day!

Answer (score 0):

Error `HTTP 405 method not allowed` means method is available on server but not allowed for given type of request.

Make sure page is accessible and `HTTPGet` or `GET` is allowed on resource/file. In your case make sure xxxx.html or link redirected is accessible.

I am assuming you Post method is successfully returning Data(Please verify). I have faced this issue many times when **POST** request is called & WebAPI is missing `[HttpPost()]` attribute over Web method called.

**UPDATE**

---

Is you IIS / Server is allowing html files? By default it allows but some people remove default handlers for security or performance

Check for Handler Mappings:

[image]

Make sure `StaticFile` entry for `*` exists and is enabled & allowed for GET & Read.

Comment: Yes bro...POST method returning the correct value web api side no problems but in javascript calling only got this error.

Comment: It's enter into the success method and at once redirects to HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used. This page!!

Comment: any chance the message is `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'` ?

Comment: Check console or network in Developer window(F12). Error will show the link you are redirecting. Try to copy that link & open in other browser window. If that is also giving 405 then we need to resolve that

Comment: I didnt get you bro..These are the causes shown:
Most likely causes:
The request sent to the Web server used an HTTP verb that is not allowed by the module configured to handle the request.
A request was sent to the server that contained an invalid HTTP verb.
The request is for static content and contains an HTTP verb other than GET or HEAD.
A request was sent to a virtual directory using the HTTP verb POST and the default document is a static file that does not support HTTP verbs other than GET or HEAD.

Comment: Is you IIS / Server is allowing html files? By default it allows but some people remove default handlers for security or performance

Comment: if the redirect is causing the issue, forget about the POST you did to fetch the redirect URI, its done, it completed, now focus your efforts on the redirect URI only. redirect means `GET` request. as it seems your API doesnt allow you to `GET`. can you show that method's controller in your asp.net project ?

Comment: In developer console also I checked redirect to that particular method while on reaching that redirection page code executes, 405 method not allowed error. Also I dont have server side code.

Comment: Check IIS mappings for html/type of file you are redirecting. Seems mapping is missing for file type or is restricted for GET. I have Updated answer

Comment: The location.href value still has the current page after I change the value too.How to assign new page url?

Comment: try giving whole url like `http://example.com/xxxx.html` instead of just html page